# Query con Node Js y MariaDb

Tags: javascript, nodejs, mariadb, callback

estoy trantando de hacer un query con **Node** y **MariaDb** , pero estoy obteniendo este error:

> GET / - - ms - -
>   (node:3244) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: pool is closed
>       at Object.module.exports.createError (/Users/dmn/Desktop/apirestIntrost/node_modules/mariadb/lib/misc/errors.js:55:10)
>       at Pool.end (/Users/dmn/Desktop/apirestIntrost/node_modules/mariadb/lib/pool.js:54:16)
>       at pool.query.then.then.catch.err (/Users/dmn/Desktop/apirestIntrost/src/models/user.js:33:18)

este es el modelo que quiero hacer y esta mi ruta.

user.js

```
const mariadb = require('mariadb');
const pool = mariadb.createPool({
     host: 'x.x.x.x', 
     user:'x', 
     password: 'x',
     connectionLimit: 5
});

if(!pool){
    console.log('conección falló');

}else{
    console.log('good conección');   
}

let userModel = {};

userModel.getUsers = (callback) => {
    pool.getConnection()
    .then(conn => {

      conn.query('SELECT * FROM `users order by id`')
        .then((rows) => {
          console.log(rows); //[ {val: 1}, meta: ... ]
          //return conn.query("INSERT INTO myTable value (?, ?)", [1, "mariadb"]);
          callback(rows);
        })
        .then((res) => {
          console.log(res); // { affectedRows: 1, insertId: 1, warningStatus: 0 }
          conn.end();
        })
        .catch(err => {
          //handle error
          conn.end();
        })

    }).catch(err => {
      //not connected
    });
};


module.exports = userModel;
```

userRoutes.js

```
const User = require('../models/user');


module.exports = (app)=>{
    app.get('/',(req,res)=>{
        User.getUsers((err,data) => {
            res.status(200).json(data);
        });  
    });

}
```

Comment: reinicia MariaDB, al parecer el pool esta lleno

Comment: lo reinicié pero ahora no resivo más que el > GET / - - ms - -

Answer (score 2):

Según veo en el código que muestras, veo un posible error que puede que te ayude a resolver el problema que tienes, a lo mejor no es la solución correcta pero me gustaría que la probaras ya que el 'Warning' que te muestra en el código esta relacionado con las Promise y lo que te quiero mostrar viene relacionado con ello, te comento.

Creo que el problema esta en el método 'mariadb.createPool()', este método te devuelve una Promise que tienes que resolverla para que no te lance el error, por lo tanto en el primer '.then()' al no devolver ningún dato no la resuelve y entonces no pasara al segundo 'then()', por lo que no cerrara la conexión y por eso  te lanza ese 'Warning', avisándote de que la conexión no esta cerrada correctamente.

Te paso el código que creo que te funcionará (siempre y cuando las opciones de la conexión sean las correctas):

user.js

```
const mariadb = require('mariadb');
const pool = mariadb.createPool({
     host: 'x.x.x.x', 
     user:'x', 
     password: 'x',
     connectionLimit: 5
});

module.exports.getUsers = () => {
   return pool.getConnection()
              .then(conn => {
                    return conn.query('SELECT * FROM `users order by id`')
              .then(rows => {
                    conn.end()
                    return rows
              })
              .catch(err => {
                    console.log(err.message)
                    conn.end()
                    return err
              })
};
```

app.js

```
const User = require('../models/user');

module.exports = (app)=>{
    app.get('/',(req,res)=>{
        User.getUsers()
            .then(data => res.status(200).json(data))
            .catch(err => res.json(err)) //Tratar el error como desees.
    });
}
```

Confírmame si te funciono.

Saludos

Comment: me da error en 'let userModel.getUsers' en el punto

Comment: Hola @E.Rawrdríguez.Ophanim, disculpa tuve un error, recién edite la respuesta correctamente. Saludos